# Solving finite sum in terms of the generalized hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, math-software, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I have the following sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}
\frac{(1-a)_{n}}{(2-b)_{n}}\,\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{n},
\end{equation}
where $a=1,2,3,\dots$, $b=2,3,4,\dots$, $c>0$, $d>0$, and $(s)_{n}$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Looking at this sum I can see that it is very similar to the definition of $_{1}F_{1}(1-a;2-b;\tfrac{d}{c})$ where
\begin{equation}
{_{p}F_{q}}(a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{p};\,b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{q};\,z)
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_{1})_{n}(a_{2})_{n}\cdots (a_{p})_{n}}{(b_{1})_{n}(b_{2})_{n}\cdots (b_{q})_{n}}\ \frac{z^{n}}{n!},
\end{equation}
is the generalized hypergeometric function. Unable to put the sum in terms of a hypergeometric function, I tried typing it into WolframAlpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+pochhammer(1-a,n)%2Fpochhammer(2-b,n)*gamma(n)%2Fn!*(d%2Fc)%5En+from+n%3D1+to+n%3Da-1) and got the following answer:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(a-1)d}{(b-2)c}\,{_{3}F_{2}}\left(1,1,2-a;\,2,3-b;\,\tfrac{d}{c}\right).
\end{equation}

**Does anyone see how this answer can be derived?**

I can see how pieces of the answer make sense, e.g. that the solution does truncate to $a-1$ terms because of the $2-a$ in the first argument of the $_{3}F_{2}$ function, but I am unable to fully reproduce the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{(a-1)d}{(b-2)c}}&\color{blue}{\,{_{3}F_{2}}\left(1,1,2-a;\,2,3-b;\,\tfrac{d}{c}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{(a-1)d}{(b-2)c}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_n(1)_n(2-a)_n}{(2)_n(3-b)_n}\,\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!n!(1-a)_{n+1}}{(n+1)!(2-b)_{n+1}}\,\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{n+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-a)_{n+1}}{(2-b)_{n+1}}\,\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{n+1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-a)_{n}}{(2-b)_{n}}\,\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{n}\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^{a-1}\frac{(1-a)_{n}}{(2-b)_{n}}\,\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n!}\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{n}}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the definition of *[hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)*.
- In (2) we multiply out and use factorials instead of the Pochhammer symbol.
- In (3) we cancel terms and simplify.
- In (4) we shift the index to start with $n=1$.
- In (5) we observe that terms with index $\geq a$ are zero.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and well written answer.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: You're welcome! :-)